# Can I change a LPPL licensed LaTeX file (template) license?

Tags: licensing, derivative-works, relicensing, lppl

I got [this .tex file](https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/doc/latex/abntex2/examples/abntex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex). I need to edit it so it becomes my thesis.

According to the LPPL license, I need to change its name, and state from what name I am renaming. But what do I do about this part?

```
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%% 
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is the abnTeX2 team, led
%% by Lauro César Araujo. Further information are available on 
%% http://www.abntex.net.br/
```

I change his name to mine. So the full new header should be like this:

```
%% Copyright 2017 **My Name**
%% Copyright 2012-2016 by abnTeX2 group at http://www.abntex.net.br/
%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%%
%% The Current Maintainer of this work is the **My Name**. 
%%
%% This work consists of a bunch of files. But originally there ware 3 files
%% which are renamed as follows:
%%
%% On 11/08/2017:
%% Renamed the `abntex2-modelo-references.bib` to `modelo-ufsc-references.bib`
%% Renamed the `abntex2-modelo-include-comandos` to `Capitulos/01/CH01.tex`
%% Renamed the `abntex2-modelo-trabalho-academico.tex` to `modelo-ufsc-main.tex`
```

Answer (score 1):

Loks OK to me.

Note that this is only relevant if you want to distribute said LaTeX files further. In which case consider carefully if your changes might benefit others, and contribute them to upstream. If not (or your changes aren't accepted), perhaps you can get the same results by e.g. overriding some part of the original in an extra file, or just define your own macros to complement the original. That way you (or whoever gets the package from you) isn't tied to this particular version (presumably upstream will fix bugs from time to time).

It says this package is in "maintenance mode", that might mean that it is superseded by some newer package that offers the same (or similar) functionality. I'd look into that before digging in.